# TempData : Argument with the same key has already been added

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, tempdata

I ran into this issue today.
I'm passing arguments between actions in an asp.net mvc4 app using tempdata like this.

```
       TempData.Add("PayerAmount", amount);
       TempData.Add("TotalAmount", totalAmount);
       TempData.Add("PayOption", paymethod);
```

and i ran into this weird error while trying to "retry" a form post:
`An item with the same key has already been added`

Why i'm getting this error? how can i workaround it and why cant the framework just silently overwrite the old key/value with the new one?

EDIT: I noticed that as long as the user session isnt closed this keeps happening...*weird*

Comment: are you trying to post the form twice before the form gets submitted ?

Comment: the first post failed...user refresh form to post again

Comment: post more of your code please.

Comment: oh, i came across a similar problem, not sure how to solve it but the workaround i chose is to disable the submit button after submit on onclick in javascript

Comment: TempData is tied up with Session, all of your TempData values will be lost when Session expires

Answer (score 0):

Use This for clear

```
TempData.Remove("PayerAmount");
TempData.Remove("TotalAmount");
TempData.Remove("PayOption");
```